# How can I add a default include path for GCC in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, include, environment-variables

I'd like GCC to include files from `$HOME/include` in addition to the usual include directories, but there doesn't seem to be an analogue to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I know I can just add the include directory at command line when compiling (or in the makefile), but I'd really like a universal approach here, as in the library case.

Comment: Here is link to GCC 4.8.1 manual where [C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables) environment variables are documented.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

Try setting `C_INCLUDE_PATH` (for C header files) or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` (for C++ header files) environment variables.

As Ciro mentioned, `CPATH` will set the path for both C and C++ (and any other language).

On Windows these may be set to semicolon-separated lists. On most other platforms they may be set to colon-separated lists.

More [details](https://web.archive.org/web/20090129230009if_/http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html) in GCC's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html).

Comment: What is this "CPATH" line that was added 2016? It seems to be completely bogus. Is it? At best, it could refer to a comment that has now been deleted. By user "[Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-ourbigbook-com)"? Does "`CPATH`" actually mean "`C_INCLUDE_PATH`"? Or is it literally "`CPATH`"? Perhaps elaborate in the answer with an explanation and/or a *direct* reference to documentation?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [`CPATH` in the GCC/CPP docs.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) Edit suggested, awaiting approval.

Answer (score 62):

Create an alias for gcc with your favorite includes.

```
alias mygcc='gcc -I /whatever/'
```

Comment: I think there should be no space after `-I`

Comment: just a matter of habit to omit the space, just like you'd type `-l<libnam>` to link Just note that creating an alias is a very poor solution, really you would build a list of your 'favorite includes' and add them in your makefile.

Comment: _"The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended."_, according to the GCC manual.

Comment: Not a good idea. This is non-composable (what if you want another dir? what if you want some other GCC switch) and may confuse various scripts or automated tools which make assumptions about gcc.

Comment: @h4unt3r why is an alias poor?

Answer (score 18):

Just a note: `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH` are not the equivalent of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` serves the `ld` (the dynamic linker at runtime) whereas the equivalent of the former two that serves your C/C++ compiler with the location of libraries is `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: This seems to be a response to [jcrossley3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-can-i-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux/558819#558819), not an answer. Stack Overflow [is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score 11):

A gcc spec file can do the job, however all users on the machine will be affected.

See [HOWTO Use the GCC specs file](https://web.archive.org/web/20200616193104/http://www.mingw.org/node/25)

Comment: The link is dead. Would be great if you could update this answer with the actual info.

Comment: @Thomas fortunately, it's still available on Archive.org!

Comment: Better than nothing, but [Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).