# CMake : Add build directory to include path

Tags: c, cmake

I'm looking for the good way to add the build directory (which is different from my source directory, a git repository) to the include path for gcc, in order to have the classic "config.h" file for portability seen during the compilation.

Comment: Not a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux/558820#558820, is it?

Comment: No I posted myself what I was looking for, it was a cmake variable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was looking for

```
include_directories (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

To add the build directory in case of out-of-source build.

Answer (score 10):

A more modern approach than the selected answer would be to use

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```

[CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) - Automatically add the current source and build directories to the include path.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you for posting this answer, you're my savior

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this -I$(DIR)?

Comment: No I found myself what I was looking for, it was a cmake variable. Thx anyway +1.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` which resolves the the subdirectory in the build directory that is currently active.

If your sources are in a subdirectory such as `src/` and you want to include files that are being generated from `src/CMakeLists.txt` then using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` might be what you are looking for.