# CMake build library dynamically as sub_directory and link to main executable

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm not very good with CMake and so I am trying to create a minimalistic example of what I would like to achieve.

I wish to write a library, which is compiled with my main project and then dynamically linked against my project executable.

This is my test project file system:

[image]

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(TestProject)

add_subdirectory(lib_wrapper)

add_executable(TestExe main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TestExe libwrapper)
target_include_directories(TestExe PUBLIC ../lib_wrapper)
target_include_directories(TestExe PUBLIC ../src)
```

lib_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library (wrapper wrapper.cpp)

target_include_directories (wrapper PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

src/main.cpp:

```
#include <src/a_header.h>

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

src/a_header.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <lib_wrapper/wrapper.h>
#include <iostream>

inline void some_func()
{
    std::cout << "some_func()" << std::endl;

    // Call a function from lib_wrapper/wrapper.h
}
```

`cmake ..` generates for the main project successfully. However, when I `make` in folder `Test` I get:

```
Test/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: src/a_header.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <src/a_header.h>
```

Could someone please help? And any additional advice to improve things is welcome.

Comment: Does this error happen in the TestExe project?

Comment: @drescherjm yes, when I `make` in Test folder

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622053/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622053/487892)

Comment: Your library target is `wrapper`, so you need to link with it, not with `libwrapper`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, I've made that change based on your comment. I don't think that affects the compiler error I experienced.

Comment: Your basic problem is the ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} folder needs to be in your includes. I think you can solve it with the link I gave you earlier or `target_include_directories(TestExe PUBLIC  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: @drescherjm that line you just posted solved it. Thank you. Please post it as an answer. What is the best way to include all headers and all source files, without listing them explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that the root folder `Test` is not in the include directories list when building the `TestExe` target.

One way to do this is to add `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` to the end of either of your `target_include_directories(TestExe PUBLIC ...` lines before the ) or you may want to replace these with this:

```
target_include_directories(TestExe PRIVATE 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} 
    ../lib_wrapper 
    .
)
```

I changed `PUBLIC` to `PRIVATE` because usually an executable target is not inherited by other targets and thus does not need to share include directories with other targets.

Your second error as @Tsyvarev mentioned in the comments is:

```
target_link_libraries(TestExe libwrapper)
```

This should be

```
target_link_libraries(TestExe wrapper)
```

since your library target name is wrapper:

```
add_library (wrapper wrapper.cpp)
```