# #import using angle brackets < > and quote marks " "

Tags: objective-c, syntax, import, package

I'm wondering what decides whether you're allowed to use `<Header.h>` or `"Header.h"` when you're importing files in Objective-C. So far my observation has been that you use the quote marks `""` for files in your project that you've got the implementation source to, and angle brackets `<>` when you're referencing a library or framework.

But how exactly does that work? What would I have to do to get my own classes to use the brackets? Right now Xcode will not allow me to do that for my own headers.

Also, by looking in some frameworks headers, I see that the headers reference each other with `<frameworkname/file.h>`. How does *that* work? It looks a lot like packages in Java, but as far as I know, there is no such thing as a package in Objective-C.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Objective-C has this in common with C/C++; the quoted form is for "local" includes of files (you need to specify the relative path from the current file, e.g. `#include "headers/my_header.h"`), while the angle-bracket form is for "global" includes -- those found somewhere on the include path passed to the compiler (e.g. `#include <math.h>`).

So to have your own headers use `< >` not `" "` you need to pass either the relative or the absolute path for your header directory to the compiler. See ["How to add a global include path for Xcode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749027/how-to-add-a-global-include-path-for-xcode) for info on how to do that in Xcode.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(VS.80).aspx) for more info.

Comment: I just had an issue with a GitHub project referencing AFNetworking as #import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h> so I had to $(SRCROOT)/lib/AFNetworking as a Header Search Path. Under this folder is another folder named AFNetworking which is how the import with angle brackets finds it with that path. Normally #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h" would work but for this project it just references it differently.

Comment: It seems the reason is same as for C/C++. Angle bracket (denoted by <> symbol) indicate that search for file other than current local directory whereas quotes (denoted by "" symbol) indicate that search for file in current local directory.

Comment: Link at end of answer is outdated.

Answer (score 18):

In C, the convention is that header files in `<>` bracket are searched in 'system' directories and `""` in user or local directories.

The definition of system and local is a bit vague, I guess. I believe it looks in system directories in include path or in CPPFLAGS for <header.h>, and local directory or directory specified with -I to compiler are searched for "header.h" files.

I assume it works similarly for Objective-C.

Answer (score 6):

To import your own classes using "< >" you have to put the header files (*.h) in the lib folder of compiler or set a SYSTEM VARIABLES ponting to your lib folder.

Answer (score 3):

**#import <> vs ""**

`<Name.h>` - `Angle brackets` tells to preprocessor to search in a **special** pre-designated system's directories. For example you import systems headers like `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` or added frameworks

`"Name.h"` - `Quotation marks` tells to preprocessor to search in a **current** directory. If a header was not found the preprocessor try to use `<Name.h>`. Usually you should use it with your project's files

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon the same problem, there are 2 types of search paths is Xcode:

```
User Header Search Paths
Header Search Paths
```

If you add your own include folders into Header Search Paths, you can use angled brackets without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Or set `Always Search User Path` to `YES` so you can use angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

With angle brackets e.g. `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` you import system files.

You use double quotes `"Person.h"` to import local files (files that you created) and to tell the compiler where to look for them.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Xcode project and you want to include it in a framework, have the header file you want to included open. Then, open Xcode's rightmost tab and under "Target Membership", click on the framework you want your file to available from.

e.g. If your framework is AlphaTools and your header, AceHeader, then you'll select AlphaTools on Target Membership so you can access `< AlphaTools/AceHeader.h`

Answer (score -6):

WHAT IS HEADER FILE ?
Header files contain definitions of functions and variables which can be incorporated into any C program by using the pre-processor #include statement. Standard header files are provided with each compiler, and cover a range of areas, string handling, mathematical, data conversion, printing and reading of variables.
Ex- #include  it contain the information about input like scanf(),and out put like printf() function and etc in a compiler.

## INCLUDE

1) #INCLUDE:-
It is a pre-processor that process before process of main function.
The main work of pre-processor is to initialize the environment of program i.e that is the program with the header file.
2).h:-
(Header file) A header file is a file with extension .h which contains C function declarations and macro definitions and to be shared between several source files.
Q) There are two types of header files: the files that the programmer writes and the files that come with your compiler ?
A)In a angular brackets  
Angular-bracket form is for "global" includes -- those found somewhere on the include path passed to the compiler (e.g. #include)
It is used for using of library function which is all ready define in compiler.
In C the convention is that header files in <> bracket are searched in 'system' directories 
B) Quote marks:-  “header.h”
quoted form is for "local" includes of files (you need to specify the relative path from the current file, e.g. #include "headers/my_header.h")
In C the convention is that header files in " " are searched in user or local directories.
In it one file to be included in another .(FILE INCLUSION).
It can be used in two cases:
Case 1:   If we have a very large program, the code is best divided int several different files,each containing a set of related functions.
Case 2:   There are some functions and micros definitions that we need at most in all programs that we write.
Ex