# Difference between #import header file with <filename> and "filename"

Tags: objective-c, syntax, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [#import using angle brackets < > and quote marks “ ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044360/import-using-angle-brackets-and-quote-marks)

I'd like to understand how the two versions of the `#import` statement work. As a  guess, maybe it is something like:

- `#import <filename>` is wired to frameworks
- `#import "file"` is for a single file

I found some other answers about this, but related to C++. I haven't been able to find information about Objective-C.

Comment: The behaviour in Objective-C is identical to that in C++ (both use the C preprocessor to expand `#include`). Your description is generally true, but can be altered with compiler flags.