# Different ways of importing

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between:

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
```

And:

```
#import "Twitter/Twitter.h"
```

Also, what is:

```
@class SomeClass
```

I am quite confused. Which one should I use?

Comment: The first two differ exactly as they do for #include in C.  The third is the moral equivalent to `class SomeClass` in C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [#import using angle brackets < > and quote marks " "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044360/import-using-angle-brackets-and-quote-marks)

Comment: See also [@class vs. #import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usally use the <> to say that the header is OUTSIDE your project, and not one of your own files. If it is your file you use "" instead. This is mostly to make it a bit more clear to yourself and other people.

In your case the use of <> is the better way to go.

The "class" keyword is used for forward declaration. In c++ it speeds up compilation and I usually use it instead of having a recursive dependency. For example if you have header A.h including B.h and B.h needs to include A.h. Instead I forward declare class A in B or whatever seems most suitable.

This question would explain it a bit too since I've only used forward declaration in C++.

[@class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import)