# Why isn't Xcode finding my MKMap Framework, causing error messages?

Tags: ios, frameworks, mapkit

I am creating an interface with an MKMapView.  However, I have been getting these error messages and I think I have linked the framework correctly.  At the beginning of the class ContactViewController header file, I #import < MapKit/MapKit.h >.

[image: Error Messages]

I believe I have correctly linked the framework so my project, as shown below.  Am I missing anything? Why is this not working?

[image: Link With Libraries]

Appreciate your help!
R

Comment: That is the right framework.  You might want to delete it, and it again, maybe even clean the project.

Comment: I just tried this... its still giving me the same error for the line: mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] init]

Comment: In your post you have spaces in the import between the brackets and MapKit/Mapkit.h  #import < MapKit/MapKit.h > ,  try it without the spaces.

Comment: Thanks - good observation.  However, I only did that because in stack overflow, the words MapKit/Mapkit.h wouldn't show up without spaces between it and the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same issue, your right to link it as you have done, however you must also include the framework in your file.

[#import using angle brackets < > and quote marks " "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044360/import-using-angle-brackets-and-quote-marks)

Hope this helps,

Bianca

Comment: Thanks Bianca, I tried doing that too but still the same error... This is at the top of my file: #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"   ... no dice.

Comment: try "include" instead of "import"