# Can't use debugger amongst Swift classes in Objective-C app

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a large Xcode project which is 99% Objective-C and C code. I've just implemented the project's first Swift class.

When I pause the debugger and enter any command, I am greeted with this message:

```
error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'Coventry_iPhone' from AST context:
error: /Users/ricky/Documents/Coventry/Config/Frameworks/iPhone/Coventry-iPhone-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: error: 'Silverlake-iPhone.h' file not found
#import "Silverlake-iPhone.h"
        ^

error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/ricky/Documents/Coventry/Config/Frameworks/iPhone/Coventry-iPhone-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Obviously something is wrong with importing a header file from another framework. Is there something akin to search paths I need to do with the debugger so it knows where to find this file? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: How did you import swift class in any Obj C file, can you show that import code

Comment: @ankit To do that I had to use `#import <Coventry_iPhone/Coventry_iPhone-Swift.h>` in my Objective-C implementation file.

Comment: use  # import "Appname-Swift.h"

Comment: @ankit We're in a framework so I have to use the target name. I tried using quotes (`#import "Coventry_iPhone/Coventry_iPhone-Swift.h"`) to no avail.

Comment: Does `/Users/ricky/Documents/Coventry/Config/Frameworks/iPhone/Coventry-iPhone-Bridging-Header.h` exist?

Comment: @shallowThought Yes it does. I think it is just struggling with the first import statement in that file, as it belongs in another framework/project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044360/import-using-angle-brackets-and-quote-marks

Answer (score 1):

After extensive trial and error, I found that `#import <Silverlake-iPhone.h>` was the syntax that worked.