# Include paths not found while compiling with g++ on MacOS

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, include, g++

I'm trying to compile the simplest program on MacOS 10.6 like:

```
$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

the following source:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
hello.cpp:1:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char* const*)’:
hello.cpp:4: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

So obviously I have to add the include path somewhere. My question is **where** can I find the include directories and **how** can add them globally (I don't want to provide the include path whenever I want to compile).

I just installed the XCode 3.1.4 and managed to compile it via Xcode, but not via command line. I found some header files in this directory:

```
/Xcode3.1.4/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

and tried to add it to the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749027/how-to-add-a-global-include-path-for-xcode) question, but no luck.

I'm developing on Linux and everything is working fine there, but I want to continue doing that on MacOS. Any help?

Comment: This works as expected on my system, no problems finding the file to include. I don't think I have anything special installed other than the regular developer tools package...

Comment: well.. I just realized that I downloaded the version 3.1.4 of Xcode, but today I found that there is a 3.2.1 out there.. and I'm pretty sure that entered the same query on Google :) So let's see if that will help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Mac, that include file is in /usr/include/c++/4.0.0/iostream .  Are you sure
you have all the command-line development tools installed? They might not be by default;
I'm pretty sure I had to install it manually when I first set up my Mac. There should be a "developer tools" package somewhere on your OS X installation media.

Or, if you want to make sure you're getting the latest version, you can download it from:
http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html

Comment: I have only ppc_intrinsics.h and stdint.h under my /usr/include/gcc/darwin/4.2 folder.

Comment: Same here (except I have 4.0), but g++ works for me.  Do you have a /usr/include/c++ directory?

Comment: Sounds like it's not fully installed, then.  There should be a "developer tools" package in your OS X installation media, maybe give that a try?  I'm pretty sure I had to do this manually when I set up my Mac.

Comment: Just edit your answer and tell me to update to the latest version from  here http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html and I'll accept this answer :D

Answer (score -4):

```
$ g++ -o example.bin example.cpp //to compile
$ ./example.bin //to run
```

It's code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```