# Import .h files surrounded with <> symbols in xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, import, header, onedrive

For example I need to import [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-ios).

But I can't use cocoapods due to some reasons.

How to import this library as source files instead? The problem I have is all the `import` macro are surrounded with `<>`. For example this doesn't work:

`#import <ADALiOS/ADUserInformation.h>`

And this works:

`#import "ADUserInformation.h"`

But if it is possible to import them without of editing the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your header files, if you want to import with angle brackets, you should pass relative or the absolute path for your header directory to the compiler. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749027/how-to-add-a-global-include-path-for-xcode) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. It works even better than described in that answer. To make `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` workable he should enable option `Always Search User Paths`