# What is the environment variable for GCC/G++ to look for .h files during compilation: LIBRARY_PATH, C_PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH or CPLUS_PATH?

Tags: gcc

Is there an environment variable for GCC/G++ to look for .h files during compilation?

I google my question, there are people say LIBRARY_PATH, C_PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_PATH, so which one is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux

Comment: I'm pretty sure `C_PATH` is not a thing; shouldn't it be `CPATH`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html

> ```
> CPATH
> C_INCLUDE_PATH
> CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
> OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
> ```
>
> Each variable's value is a list of directories separated by a special character, much like PATH, in which to look for header files. The special character, `PATH_SEPARATOR`, is target-dependent and determined at GCC build time. For Microsoft Windows-based targets it is a semicolon, and for almost all other targets it is a colon.
>
> CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if specified with `-I`, but after any paths given with `-I` options on the command line. This environment variable is used regardless of which language is being preprocessed.
>
> The remaining environment variables apply only when preprocessing the particular language indicated. Each specifies a list of directories to be searched as if specified with `-isystem`, but after any paths given with `-isystem` options on the command line.
>
> In all these variables, an empty element instructs the compiler to search its current working directory. Empty elements can appear at the beginning or end of a path. For instance, if the value of `CPATH` is `:/special/include`, that has the same effect as '`-I. -I/special/include`'.

I think that most setups avoid using the environment variables and instead pass the include directories in the command line using the `-I` option.  there will usually be a makefile variable or an IDE setting to control what gets passed to  `-I`.

Comment: Can you summarize the differences between them? In particular, the difference between CPATH and C_INCLUDE_PATH?

Comment: The posted answer is a summary of the differences.  The main one is that `CPATH` is used regardless of the language being compiled and `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is used only for C.

Answer (score 13):

Just look at the [actual gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html). It's all explained there.

To summarize:

- LIBRARY_PATH is for the linker, not for header files (used when looking for libraries requested by a `-l` option)
- CPATH specifies directories to look for header files in (like the `-I` option)
- C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH are like CPATH, but for C/C++ respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you're not sure which paths are being checked on your system you can use

cpp -v

Which will tell you which paths are being checked for .h files, the output includes sections:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
```