# How to permanently adding directories to the GCC include search path?

Tags: c, header, include

I'm running OSX 10.6.6. I have installed Apples GCC- version 4.2.1. I'm writing myself a nice little library- things for debugging, data storage algorithms, and the like. I've stored all the headers and .c files in a nice little folder called 'mylib' in my C folder. I'd like to add that folder to the GCC search path, so that I can type, say,

```
/* ... */

    #include <mylib/debug.h>

/* ... */
```

and have it work perfectly. How can I either add /Users/Henry/coding_stuff/c/include/mylib to the GCC search path, or have a reference to the folder in /usr/include? I'd like to not have to replace /usr/include/mylib with the one in my C folder every time I make a trivial change. So, how can it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

A symbolic link will work:

```
sudo ln -s /Users/Henry/coding_stuff/c/include/mylib /usr/include/mylib
```

A more traditional way to solve this problem is to use the compiler's `-I` flag to add your search path:

```
gcc -I /Users/Henry/coding_stuff/c/include/mylib -c -o example.o example.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `.bashrc`:

```
export INCLUDE_PATH=/Users/Henry/coding_stuff/c/include/mylib
```

Comment: Yeah! Thats it woman thx!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to equal the path.  Most likely in your .bashrc.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libs
```

Sorry this should actually be LIBRARY_PATH for the build; LD_LIBRARY_PATH is for runtime library linking.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libs
```

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not for #include path resolution.

Comment: LIBRARY_PATH is not for #include paths either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu14.04 and gcc.

gcc adds `C_INCLUDE_PATH` to the list of search directories.
You can use `-v` option to see where gcc actually searchs.
(`INCLUDE_PATH` does not work for me.)

So, you can add the following to `.bashrc`:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Users/Henry/coding_stuff/c/include/mylib
```

I found the official documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html