# GNU C compiler cannot locate header file

Tags: c, header, compilation

I have installed a package libstree on my machine (x86_64/Redhat Linux).

Have followed the instructions ( `./configure --prefix=/usr; make check; make install`) to install the package.

Have checked that the relevant header files are in the `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` directories.

However when I try to compile a test program I get an error message:

```
test.c:6:25: fatal error: lst_structs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

`lst_structs.h` is present in the `/usr/include/stree` directory.

Anyone have any thoughts as to why the GNU C compiler cannot locate the header file?

Comment: Are you including the file with `#include <stree/lst_structs.h>` or `#include <lst_structs.h>`?

Comment: Please show how you are including the file.

Comment: Did you do `#include <stree/lst_structs.h>`, or `#include <lst_structs.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

As it's in an /include sub-directory, you need to explicitly mention it (see comments above), or adjust your lib include path, as outlined on this old stackoverflow post:
[How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)