# cmake cannot exclude /usr/include when building for Android

Tags: android, linux, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm building parquet-cpp project on Ubuntu for Android using cmake 3.10 (by following tutorials "Cross Compiling for Android with a Standalone Toolchain" in this [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android-with-a-standalone-toolchain)). I got this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:28:
/usr/include/features.h:391:10: fatal error: 'gnu/stubs.h' file not found
#include <gnu/stubs.h>
```

I checked compiling command and found an argument `-isystem /usr/include`. I tried to exclude /usr/include from search paths but I failed. This is the full command:

`<standalone_toolchain>/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=<standalone_toolchain> --sysroot=<standalone_toolchain>/sysroot  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Dthriftz_EXPORTS -I<source_dir>/parquet-cpp/build/thrift_ep-prefix/src/thrift_ep-build/lib/cpp -I<source_dir>/parquet-cpp/build/thrift_ep-prefix/src/thrift_ep/lib/cpp -I<source_dir>/parquet-cpp/build/thrift_ep-prefix/src/thrift_ep-build -I<source_dir>/parquet-cpp/build/thrift_ep-prefix/src/thrift_ep/lib/cpp/src -isystem /usr/include -isystem <standalone_toolchain>/sysroot/usr/include -isystem <standalone_toolchain>/include/c++/4.9.x -isystem <standalone_toolchain>/include/c++/4.9.x/arm-linux-androideabi/bits  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes --sysroot <standalone_toolchain>/sysroot -Qunused-arguments  -ggdb -O0 -g -fPIC -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-long-long -Wno-c++11-long-long -Wno-deprecated-register -pthread -g -fPIC   -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/thriftz.dir/src/thrift/transport/TZlibTransport.cpp.o -c <source_dir>/parquet-cpp/build/thrift_ep-prefix/src/thrift_ep/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TZlibTransport.cpp`

I've tried lots of ways I found out when googling (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778014/exclude-system-include-path-in-cmake) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143829/how-to-exclude-usr-include-path-from-linux-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but nothing works.

Can anyone here help me? Note that I'm a newbie to cross compiling :(

Answer (score -1):

if you mean by exclude is to delete:
then type this in the terminal --> `sudo gksu nautilus` a new file manager window will open were you can access all files as root, now reach you file then delete it.

Comment: No, I meant I want to exclude "-isystem /usr/include" from the compiling command generated by cmake :)

Comment: I observed the same issue with cmake v3.17. For earlier version such as v3.4 this issue is not present. Try older version of cmake.