# Compiling with MinGW32 GCC. Only tell link libraries once?

Tags: c, gcc, command-line, compilation, mingw

I'm compiling programs via command-line with mingw32 gcc. As the source files increase, I'm running into some problems. Firstly, consider the following script:

```
gcc -Wall -I"MyDir" -I"MyDir2" -L"MyLibDir" -L"MyLibDir2" -l lib1 -l lib2 -l lib3 -c file.c
gcc -Wall -I"MyDir" -I"MyDir2" -L"MyLibDir" -L"MyLibDir2" -l lib1 -l lib2 -l lib3 -c file2.c
gcc -Wall -I"MyDir" -I"MyDir2" -L"MyLibDir" -L"MyLibDir2" -l lib1 -l lib2 -l lib3 -c file3.c
gcc -o myprog.exe file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

Now, can't I just tell `gcc` the compiler directories `-I`, linker directories `-L` and link libraries `-l` only once and then compile the second and third source file with the same options without having to retype them? Something like

```
gcc -define-options -Wall -I"MyDir" -I"MyDir2" -L"MyLibDir" -L"MyLibDir2" -l lib1 -l lib2 -l lib3 
gcc -Wall -c file1.c
gcc -Wall -c file2.c
gcc -Wall -c file3.c
gcc -o myprog.exe file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no, you can't. But that's why make and Makefiles were invented :) I think [this tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) is more than enough to get you started on writing a decent Makefile for your small project.

PS: The quick & dirty way would be to just write a simple bash script that holds the include directories in a variable, but Makefiles are a much better option in my opinion, since you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

PS2: Out of curiosity, I found that, indeed, there is a way to do it. You just need to define some environment variables. See here for details: [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

Comment: A nit with the linked tutorial: calling a target `all` does nothing special. `make` considers the first target read while `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is empty to be the default, unless an assignment to the special variable `.DEFAULT_GOAL` changes this. See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html .