# Linux - compiling c++ project files from different locations

Tags: c++, c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

I was wondering is it possible to compile together files from different locations if they are included in the code itself? 
Lets say the header file is in another location but there is #include "header.h" in the cpp file.
I was looking for answer here on the site but the only thing I found was how to compile multiple files from the same location.

edit: I use g++ compiler on linux

Comment: I added one possible duplicate, but there are possibly many more here already. Note that the correct answer depends on your build system and/or compiler which you haven't given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put

```
#include "adress"
```

adress would be like C:/Users/Files.../header.h