# How to fix C program error for Openmpi with netbeans running on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c, netbeans-7, openmpi

I am trying to run a MPI program with C language.
I have installed GCC compiler and the openmpi libraries. I am running ubuntu Linux and Netbeans IDE. My challenge is that after including ‘mpi.h’ in my header file and compiling the application, I still get ‘fatal error : cannot find file mpi.c’. I have the files in home/user/lib/openmpi/include, but I cant get it too work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `mpi.c`, what's that? Better show actual compile output, and show how the project is set up... What does it use as build system, ant or make or what?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the compiler to `/path/mpicc` and the debugger to `mpirun`. This should work, although I did not test it, but probably the best way to compile MPI code is via terminal.

If you really depend on the IDE you cound try writing your code with it (to take advantage of auto-completion and such) and compile it in terminal using `mpicc -o main.exe main.cpp [other .cpp files]` and run it with `mpirun -np number_of_processes_to_use ./main.exe [args]`. You could write a small script or a Makefile to do it all in one command.

Good luck!

Comment: He's on linux, exe not going to help him much. ;(

Comment: @CasualT, I'm also on Linux and I still suffix `.exe` to the names of my executable files. It helps to distinguish them from scripts and batch job files.

Comment: well, fair enough I guess, just can confuse people ;)

Answer (score 0):

to save yourself some sanity, I'd recommend opening up a terminal and going from there (at least until you figure out what's what).

Also, using the mpi compiler to do things would simplify your life. (and likely automatically solve the missing source issue, as it should know where they are by default).

If you still can't locate them during compile then I'd look at adding the location where mpi.c & mpi.h are located to your C Include Path:    [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

Comment: If you are running things on a shared system (eg. super computer...because why else would you be running mpi :P), then the steps are potentially a little more involved.  Depending on your environment I might be able to help you out a bit more, so comment if you are still stuck. :)