# About how to work on makefile

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

i'm working on a "makefile" on an old version of php (php-5.3.22)

```
fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <ft2build.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have properly installed my freetype2 and I guess the above line is asking the file with the path
"/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h"

how should I add in the above file to the above path?

(I can't use the `gcc -c /usr/include/freetype2/` method since it will further refer to files in it while the current working path is /..../php-5.3.22)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should change the `makefile`. Caveat, many software have their `makefile` *generated* by some configuration procedure (e.g. `./configure` for GNU software using `autoconf`)

If your `makefile` is not generated, you should change some `CFLAGS` (or similar) variable in the `makefile`  to add some `-I` option (e.g. `-I /usr/include/freetype2/` and others...).

If your `makefile` is generated, you need to regenerate it in the appropriate way to get it correct. Perhaps by passing appropriate options to `./configure`

Comment: thanks for answering, i was following a guide which asks me to input a lot of arguments in ./configure but now i understand how it works, then i have it work well with nature configure and then make...