# fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory #include "jni_md.h"

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, gcc

While executing `gcc` command on ubuntu for generating .a or .so file for JNI, getting below error for both openjdk 8 / oraclejdk8.

```
$gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include -c MainImpl1.c -o MainImpl1.o

In file included from MainImpl1.c:1:0:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h:45:20: fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory
 #include "jni_md.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.

$gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -c MainImpl1.c -o MainImpl1.o

In file included from MainImpl1.c:1:0:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/jni.h:45:20: fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory
 #include "jni_md.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have given example for generating .a file, but same issue observed for .so file generation also.

But same `gcc` command works for openjdk7/oraclejdk7.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think you added the include directory that includes `jni_md.h` which is [platform dependent](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2011-June/001918.html).

Try

```
$gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -c MainImpl1.c -o MainImpl1.o
```

or

```
$gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -c MainImpl1.c -o MainImpl1.o
```

If you don't know where jni_md.h is, use `find`:

```
find / -name jni_md.h 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Depending on your preference, sometimes it's nicer to [add the include directories globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/558819/1509695) after finding them, like if you're building someone else's project without wanting to fiddle their make files.

Answer (score 1):

for **“jni_md.h”** No Such file or directory Error include below path with gcc:

```
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/include/linux
```

for **“jni.h”** No Such file or directory Error include below path with gcc:

```
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/include
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cheers ;-)