# PYTHONPATH counterpart for importing C++ libraries

Tags: python, c++, caffe

I am trying to rewrite the pycaffe code using C++ Caffe API. However, I get stuck at the very beginning. None of the following

```
#include <caffe.hpp> 

#include <caffe/caffe.hpp> 

#include <home/username/caffe/caffe.hpp>
```

works because the path to the caffe is not known the way it is given by PYTHONPATH in the pycaffe code. How then do I add the caffe module in the C++ code?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler and linker where the header and library files are located. The common way to do it is with an option like `-I` (upper-case i) for header files. Like e.g. `g++ -I/location/of/caffe/headers ...`

Comment: That last one could work if you use the absolute path, e.g. `/home/username/caffe/`.

Answer (score 3):

The path to directories with additional headers must be specified to the compiler. Often, using `-I<include-path>` command line switch, e.g. `-I/home/username/caffe`.

Your build system may offer a few different ways of adding additional include directories.

Answer (score 0):

The counterpart of the `PYTHONPATH` is `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, which can be used in the following way:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/home/username/caffe/include/
```

and then

```
#include "caffe/caffe.hpp"
```

There may be some other path headers missing, in such a case adding the paths to those headers to the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` will solve the issue.

Comment: see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/558819/1714410) for more information.