# OpenCV C++ Linux g++ compiling

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I just installed OpenCV-3.4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. I am able to compile my C++ files only when I run the g++ command with `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` 
Is it possible for me to compile the c++ file without using these additional flags
How can I tell g++ to automatically look at /usr/include/opencv for the .h files everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding to the include path see this question: [How to add a default include path for GCC in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

A better solution however is to write a shell script to compile your code rather than having to type in the command line every time.

The best solution is to use a proper build system which will save you a lot of pain in the future, just a few of the many available options:

- GNU make
- cmake
- google gyp
- google gn
- ninja

Comment: I tried the simplest option of adding CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH to my .bashrc file and it didn't solve the problem. I got an error message saying stdlib.h couldn't be found

Comment: What exactly did you add and what is the resulting error message?

Comment: My opencv header files are stored in /usr/include. Therefore I added CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include. I got a new error message saying stdlib.h not found. All the other reference errors to opencv functions have disappeared though

Comment: Consider suggested CMake tool.